# Can't able to set the product attribute programmatically in magento through observer

Tags: magento, observers

I want to update the products description attribute after the product save.so for this i am using the observer called `catalog_product_save_after` and depending on some condition i create the description for the product and i will save the description of the products by following code

```
product->setDescription();
product->save();
```

the problem is when i am calling the `product->save();` the site is loading and loading later i found that `product->save();` this function is again calling the `catalog_product_save_after`. that's why it is going into the infinite loop.

Please help me to set the description for the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You can use `catalog_product_save_before` and just use `$product->setDescription('something')` (without the save).
**Option 2**
Make your observer run only once.

```
function doSomething($observer) {
    //some code here
    $id = $product->getId();
    if (!Mage::registry('observer_already_executed_'.$id)) {
        //do your magic here
        Mage::register('observer_already_executed_'.$id, 1);
    }
}
```